# Find edge in a liine OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to find an edge(of an object) in a line. I know sobel and canny etc detection methods detect the edges, but I need to find edge points of an object as a (x,y) pixel coordinate only in a line.

NI Vision Builder have similar tool as Find Edge I attached example.

Is this possible in OpenCV or other image processing libraries?

[image: Find Edge]

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03n3n.jpg)

Thank you!

I tried masked image with a line and find contours but didn't work.

Comment: yes, opencv doesn't have a "machine vision" module yet, but it should. MV commonly uses these operations for reliable localization of features and objects. -- (1) extract 1D signal from image (scanlines are easy, arbitrarily angled lines could use an affine warp) (2) analyze 1D signal for either absolute thresholds or extrema in gradient -- if you would like a more fleshed out answer, please provide a source picture without annotations.

Comment: Please I didn't understand 1D signal analyzing. I need more than, I just added the raw image. I want to find edge coordinate this object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do that using Python/OpenCV/Numpy.

- Read the input
- Convert Grayscaled
- Threshold to binary
- Specify a row
- Get all the white pixels along the row as the data
- Find the min and max x coordinates (leftmost and rightmost) of white pixels along the row
- Draw the line for the row on a copy of the image
- Draw a circle for each of the min and max x coordinates on the row
- Save the output

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('03n3n.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
h, w = img.shape[:2]

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# specify row
row = 620

# find min and max of white region at given row
data = np.where(thresh[row:row+1, 0:h] == 255)
x1, x2 = np.amin(data[1]), np.amax(data[1])
pt1 = (x1,row)
pt2 = (x2,row)
print("min:", x1)
print("max:", x2)

# draw line and 2 points
result = img.copy()
result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv2.line(result, (0, row), (w, row), (0,255,0), 1)
cv2.circle(result, pt1, 3, (0,0,255), 3)
cv2.circle(result, pt2, 3, (0,0,255), 3)

# save result
cv2.imwrite('03n3n_line_pts.jpg', result)

# show results
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

[image]

```
min: 1240
max: 1643
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but now I have a question. Can I use this method for angular search lines not vertical? Like 60 degree or 30 degree lines

Comment: Yes, just rotate the image so that the line is either horizontal or vertical.